# Get list of counts by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One containing a list of applications. And another one containing counts associated to them every week. Now I want to get as a result the app name and the count for this week and the previous. Let me explain this.

app:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Office 2007 |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | Office 2010 |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | Office 2013 |
+----+-------------+
```

count:

```
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| id | app_id | count | date       |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | 200   | 2016-01-11 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 2  | 2      | 500   | 2016-01-11 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 3  | 3      | 750   | 2016-01-11 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 4  | 1      | 180   | 2016-01-18 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 5  | 2      | 378   | 2016-01-18 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
| 6  | 3      | 1000  | 2016-01-18 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+
```

And this is the result I need. I need all the applications with the count of this week and the previous:

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| app         | count_this_week | count_prev_week |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Office 2007 | 180             | 200             |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Office 2010 | 378             | 500             |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Office 2013 | 1000            | 750             |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

A script runs every week which fills the `count` table. And now I need to get a report also on a weekly basis.
Honestly I'm a bit lost as I don't know how to declare the conditions for the columns.

Comment: Do you mean current month last week or last week in the year?

Comment: Previous week. Modified question to be clear.

Comment: Do you mean previous week? Last week meaning is different. Last week can be the last week of current month.

Comment: First, do you have a table you can use that store dates? and second, count_this_week - if its monday, that means its the count of sunday and monday, or 7 days ago and prev is 8-14 days ago

Comment: @DMayuri That is grammar, but anyway let me tell you that "last week" refers to the previous week: "Last week" is the calendar week preceding the present week." http://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?16344-this-past-week-last-week-in-the-past-week

Comment: which day do you want to consider as 1st day of week. That is Monday or Sunday?

Comment: Week means from Monday to Sunday. So this week means -> this Monday to this Sunday. Last/previous week means -> Last/prev Monday to Last/prev Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to group first by `DATEPART(WEEK,C.date),name` and then split the counts into 2 columns using another `GROUP BY`. Something like this

**EDIT**

If there are exactly 1 record per week per app, you can do with just one `group by` like this.

```
SELECT
    appname,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weekno = 0 THEN sumcount ELSE 0 END) as thisweek,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weekno = 1 THEN sumcount ELSE 0 END) as lastweek
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - DATEPART(WEEK,C.date) as weekno,
        name as appname,
        count as sumcount
    FROM App A 
    INNER JOIN CountTable C ON A.[id] = C.[app_id]
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEK,C.date) BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1  AND DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
)T
GROUP BY appname
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    appname,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weekno = 0 THEN sumcount ELSE 0 END) as thisweek,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weekno = 1 THEN sumcount ELSE 0 END) as lastweek
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - DATEPART(WEEK,C.date) as weekno,
        name as appname,
        SUM(count) as sumcount
    FROM App A INNER JOIN CountTable C ON A.[id] = C.[app_id]
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEK,C.date) BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1  AND DATEPART(WEEK,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,C.date),name
) AS T
GROUP BY appname
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89fee/1)**

**Output**

```
|     appname | thisweek | lastweek |
|-------------|----------|----------|
| Office 2007 |      180 |      200 |
| Office 2010 |      378 |      500 |
| Office 2013 |     1000 |      750 |
```

Comment: The `SUM` is not really required as there is only one count per week.

Comment: In that case you could do without the initial `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic query with a variable for the current week day:

```
DECLARE @week date = '2016-01-18';

WITH data AS (
    SELECT a.name, c.[count] 
        , w = CASE WHEN c.[date] = @week THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM @Counts c
    INNER JOIN @Apps a ON c.app_id = a.id
    WHERE [date] = @week OR [date] = DATEADD(day, -7, @week)
)
SELECT App = name, count_this_week = [0], count_prev_week = [1]
FROM data d
PIVOT (
    MAX([count])
    FOR w IN ([0], [1])
) p
```

**Output:**

```
App         count_this_week count_prev_week
Office 2007 180             200
Office 2010 378             500
Office 2013 1000            750
```

**Your data:**

```
DECLARE @Apps TABLE ([id] int, [name] varchar(11));
DECLARE @Counts TABLE([id] int, [app_id] int, [count] int, [date] date);

INSERT INTO @Apps([id], [name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Office 2007'),
    (2, 'Office 2010'),
    (3, 'Office 2013')
;

INSERT INTO @Counts([id], [app_id], [count], [date])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 200, '2016-01-11'),
    (2, 2, 500, '2016-01-11'),
    (3, 3, 750, '2016-01-11'),
    (4, 1, 180, '2016-01-18'),
    (5, 2, 378, '2016-01-18'),
    (6, 3, 1000, '2016-01-18')
;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM count 
JOIN app ON app.id=count.app_id
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-01-11'
```